# mysql join 2 tables - show all rows from one table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables, like so:
table "a" contains:

```
id|name

stock1|fullname
stock2|fullname2
stock3|fullname3
```

table "b" contains product quantities for given stock.

```
id|stock_id|quantity|product_id|
1|stock1|3|13
2|stock3|4|13
3|stock1|1|5
4|stock2|2|2
```

Now I would need to combine those two tables, so that each product takes its stock full name from table "a", and if its quanitity is not given for stock, it would still show the row with the quanitity as 0.

So from my example, product_id 13 would show as:

```
stock|quanitity|product_id|stock_fullname
stock1|3|13|fullname1
stock2|0|13|fullname2
stock3|4|13|fullname3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a LEFT JOIN to achieve this.

```
SELECT a.id AS stock, COALESCE(b.quanitity,0), b.product_id, a.name AS stock_fullname
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
  ON a.id = b.stock_id
  AND b.product_id = 13
```

Comment: With this, I end up with `stock1|3|13|fullname1 and stock3|4|13|fullname3` - The 2nd row doesn't get selected because it does not have stock id row set...

Comment: Sorry, screwed up with the query. I've changed the answer to not use the where clause and filter table b in the join instead - see if that makes it better...

Comment: Yes, it seems, using a "WHERE" is a no go with a left join, because that gets applied after the join, thus filtering out rows with null. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use a [LEFT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), although the records with no quantity might show as NULL rather than zero. Something like:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM table_a a
    LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.stock_id = b.stock_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT stock,COALESCE(quanitity,0),product_id,stock_fullname FROM stock JOIN product
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should work for your example:

```
SELECT a.id stock if(b.quantity IS NULL, 0, b.quantity), 
       b.product_id, a.name stock_fullname
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a b.stock = a.id
WHERE b.product_id = 13;
```

Comment: This will not pull out the stock2 rows as required.

Comment: That was the same as my initial attempt, but still won't get the stock2 row - I have edited my answer, which should now work as intended...

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer join so that rows from the a table without a corresponding row in b are still considered. An inner join, by contrast, insists that you have a matching row. If you are pulling a value from the table where you don't have a row, you get NULL. Syntax varies between DBs and there is a distinction made depending on if it's the table on the left or right that gets the fake rows.

see other answers for syntax.

Comment: I am using LEFT join, isn't that what you mean by outer join?

Comment: The syntax is "LEFT", but its a left outer join, meaning you get all the rows from the LEFT table, regardless if there are matching rows on the right or not.

Comment: But I am using left join, still - it only spits out rows that match the ON condition. If stock_id and id don't match (for the given product id) - It simply does not display it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `LEFT JOIN` to achieve this.

```
SELECT a.id AS stock, COALESCE(b.quanitity,0), b.product_id, a.name AS stock_fullname
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
  ON a.id = b.stock_id
  AND b.product_id = 13
```